# How to store to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, meteor, react-hooks

I'm making a method with React Hooks and jQuery that works as follows:

When the `ctrl` key is pressed it is possible to select multiple rows from a table.
I want to store the id of this row in an array only when ctrl is clicked, but every time I click in a row it seems the array restarts instead of store all the ids of cliked rows.

Furthermore I am using a hook due to the fact the array does not exist out of this jquery code. Please can anyone help me? This is my code, thanks in advance.

```
 const Mapa = (props) => {
  const [groupOfIntersections, setGroupOfIntersections] = useState('');
  const arrayOfInt = [];

  $('.ui.small.celled.table tbody tr').on('click', (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      if($(e.target.parentNode).hasClass("active")) {
        $(e.target.parentNode).removeClass("active");
      } else {
        arrayOfInt.push($(e.target.parentNode).attr('class'));
        console.log('arrayOfInt', arrayOfInt);
        setGroupOfIntersections(arrayOfInt);
        $(e.target.parentNode).addClass("active");
      }
    } else if (!e.ctrlKey){
      $('.ui.small.celled.table tbody tr').removeClass("active");
      $(e.target.parentNode).addClass("active");
    }
  });
  
  console.log('groupOfIntersections', groupOfIntersections);
  console.log('arrayOfInt', arrayOfInt);

      .
      .
      .
};
```

Comment: do you mean that the `ctrl` key is held down, rather than clicked?

Comment: Also I am not so familiar with React but if I was going to make an observation you create the array every time the included code (I assume the hook) fires. Because you are creating multiple click events to select multiple items this code will fire each time, each time creating a new, single-item array with your last clicked item in it. To change this I would imagine you need to store a variable in browser cache or something along those lines

Comment: I think that this article might help you with caching to the browser in React, I don't understand the 'use state' stuff but otherwise it looks ok: https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react

Comment: Yes Scott I mean ctrl is held down

Comment: jquery and react have ***very*** orthogonal ways of handling UI and they generally don't mix well (DOM manipulation is anti-pattern in React). But yes, react works by maintaining a "state machine" with each update returning a new object reference each render cycle. From your snippet it isn't very clear what you're trying to accomplish and other than it looks like the "shell" of a component nothing internal to it resembles react other the the useState hook. So I ask, is your app more jquery or is it a react app? You kind of need to pick one or the other.

Comment: If I can not  use jquery and react, how can I select multiple rows and store the row Id??

Comment: Store what you need in react state. Store the row id's of "selected" rows and then render the rows with selected state (versus DOM manipulation).

Comment: arrayOfInt "Resets" everytime because its declared within the same scope  as the push. Try declare it above the function.

Comment: You don't mix React and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

there is something went wrong with this `arrayOfInt` constant,
actually you do not need to extra object, because you can perform all the action by using existing `groupOfIntersections` object.

```
 const Mapa = (props) => {
   const [groupOfIntersections, setGroupOfIntersections] = useState('');       

$('.ui.small.celled.table tbody tr').on('click', (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      if($(e.target.parentNode).hasClass("active")) {
        $(e.target.parentNode).removeClass("active");
      } else {
        let tempGroup = [...groupOfIntersections]
        tempGroup.push($(e.target.parentNode).attr('class'));
        console.log('tempGroup', tempGroup);
        setGroupOfIntersections(tempGroup);
        $(e.target.parentNode).addClass("active");
      }
    } else if (!e.ctrlKey){
      $('.ui.small.celled.table tbody tr').removeClass("active");
      $(e.target.parentNode).addClass("active");
    }
  });     
  console.log('groupOfIntersections', groupOfIntersections);
  console.log('arrayOfInt', tempGroup);

      .
      .
      .
};
```